# Page break in Quarto markdown

Tags: markdown, quarto

I have recently started using Quarto markdown.
Unfortunately following their documentation to generate a page break within my document with `{{< pagebreak >}}` does not work.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you building to one of the [supported formats](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/shortcodes.html#raw-output) for pagebreak? And what version of Quarto are you using (pagebreak was added this past April)?

Comment: Thanks so much! I was using an older version where it was not supported.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286406/how-do-i-create-page-breaks-with-html-documents-in-quarto/75286686#75286686)