# How do I create page breaks with html documents in Quarto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I would like to render to a paged html document.  I see instructions here for placing `{{< pagebreak >}}` between chunks to produce this, but I don't see the intended result in the rendered document.  What did I do wrong?

Here is the code and I placed a screenshot of the document below.  Thank you!

https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/markdown-basics.html

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: article
editor: source
---

```{r}
1+1
```

{{< pagebreak >}}

```{r}
2+2
```

{{< pagebreak >}}

```{r}
3+3
```
````

[image: rendered document]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot see it right away in the preview. You have to press `Ctrl+P` (on Windows) or add a button inside your html file,e.g.

```
<button onclick="window.print(); return false;" /> Print </button>
```

to see that it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  I see what you mean about the print.  Is there any way to separate the pages in the browser view, kind of like a `revealjs` presentation where the slides appear in the browser as separate pages?